# Bitmap not resizing correctly on certain phones

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to resize a bitmap to a certain size and it works for me (I have Samsung s10). But for my friend who has Samsung a70 it doesn't resize the bitmap correctly.
I tried to resize every bitmap in my app to 50x50 but even that wont work. I have multiple screens in my app and it doesn't work just on my game screen, which has nothing different to it than the other screens.
This is how I resized the bitmap

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true);
```

When I checked in my friend's phone it resized to a bitmap larger than that. I checked it by drawing a 50x50 rectangle over it, and the bitmap was larger than the rectangle.
A few bitmap are resized which are with different sizes and some worked in different screens when I resized them. In the game screen I resize them smaller so maybe that could be part of the reason the problem is happening.

Comment: The bitmap is 3456x2345 ?

Comment: I added some more details to the question

Comment: But you did not tell the  resolutions i asked for. Sigh..

Comment: The bitmaps aren't large. I added the information for stating that the resolutions aren't the problem here